# ValueError: Could not find a default download directory of nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have problem on import nltk.
I configured apache and run some sample python code, it worked well on the browser.
The URL is : /localhost/cgi-bin/test.py.
When I import the nltk in test.py its not running. The execution not continue after the "import nltk" line.And it gives me that error ValueError: Could not find a default download directory 
But when I run in the command prompt its working perfect.
how to remove this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Problem is raised probably because you don't have a default directory created for your ntlk downloads. If you are on a Windows Platform, All you need to do is to create a directory named "nltk_data" in any of your root directory and grant write permissions to that directory. The Natural Language Tool Kit initially searches for the destination named "nltk_data" in all of the root directories.

For Instance: Create a folder in your C:\ drive named "nltk_data"

After Making sure everything is done fine, execute your script to get rid of this error.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: If the default directory was missing altogether, then running the script from the prompt would cause the same error, which it doesn't, according to the OP.

Comment: @lenz creating a custom directory will be safe, time-saving and will be a better approach instead of trying some glitches in the script. The same problem if raised for the prompt, can be rectified using the approach I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: As I understand the OP, the problem wasn't that the nltk_data directory was missing, but rather that it wasn't found by the CGI script (although it existed somewhere). Apparently, your answer still helped, as it got accepted.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

1. NLTK package tries to find the `os.environ["APPDATA"]` variable to load it's contents.
2. XAMPP or any other CGI server doesn't load all of the os variables which are generally available on windows.

Hence we must explicitly provide The APPDATA SET Variable.
This can be done via 2 methods.

**Solution**

1. Inside Python itself before loading anything from nltk package.
   By adding the appdata folder path.

```py
   import os
   os.environ['APPDATA'] = r"C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming"
```

2. Set the environment variable in Xampp's http.conf
   file by adding this Line to it.

   `SetEnv APPDATA "${APPDATA}"`

Comment: This worked. The important thing is to set env variables before calling any imports. @Tomrock has mentioned it. I am rephrasing hoping it saves some time for others.

Answer (score 0):

The environment in which your CGI script is executed is not the same as when you run it in from a terminal or similar. Specifically, environment variables like `$PYTHONPATH` might not be set to what you need.

An ugly but safe work-around is adding the needed directories inside the script, before any third-party import statements:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/package-parent')  # change this to what you actually need
import nltk
```

To find the location of NLTK or whatever causes trouble, import it in an interactive session.
Then, typing the module/package name will print the location:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk
<module 'nltk' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py'>
```

So, you would append '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages' to `sys.path` in this case.

I'm not entirely sure if this also applies to the "default download directory", but you can give it a try.

Comment: I'm just guessing out of the blue, more or less, as you don't give a lot of information in your post. If you update the question to include more details about what exactly you are doing, what exactly happens under what circumstances, then I'll try to update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on being imported, the `nltk` tries to initialize a `Downloader` object (even though you have not tried to download any resources), and fails to identify a usable download location. The easiest way to make it happy is to define `NLTK_DATA` in the environment, initialized to a folder that (a) exists, and (b) your server has write access to.

In case that's not possible for some reason, let's take a look at the code that throws the error. The function `default_download_dir()` in `nltk\downloader.py` first looks for writeable locations in `nltk.data.path` (initialized from `NLTK_DATA`). If it fails to find any, it makes one last try: it tries for a folder `nltk_data` in your HOME directory (except on Windows). Evidently, your environment settings prevent Python from resolving `~/` to your HOME directory, leading to the error.

```
# On Windows, use %APPDATA%
if sys.platform == 'win32' and 'APPDATA' in os.environ:
    homedir = os.environ['APPDATA']

# Otherwise, install in the user's home directory.
else:
    homedir = os.path.expanduser('~/')
    if homedir == '~/':
        raise ValueError("Could not find a default download directory")
```

So figure out what you can do to your environment to make this function happy.